# Deployment error in local pc using visual studio

Tags: windows

I am getting problem while deploying fake driver in my local windows virtual Computer.
I am getting error like,

> Deploying driver files for project "C:\ioctl\sys\sioctl-Package\sioctl-Package.vcxproj".  Deployment may take a few minutes...
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\x64\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment8.0.targets(69,9): error : Kernel mode drivers cannot be deployed to the local machine
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\x64\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment8.0.targets(69,9): error : Value cannot be null.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Platforms\x64\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment8.0.targets(69,9): error : Parameter name: path
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========